# Why doesn't Express bundle a body parser?

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I understand how `body-parser` works, but I don't know why this functionality would not come out-of-the-box with Express. It seems kind of silly, the functionality it provides is very basic. Why can't express get data from a `POST` request without `body-parser`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express 3 did bundle more middleware, however [as expressed in the Express wiki](https://github.com/strongloop/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x#overview), the reason the Express developers unbundled them was to allow "middleware to receive fixes, updates, and releases, without impacting Express release cycles (and vice-versa)."

Express 4 only bundles static file serving middleware.